# Which way should I import React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I'm not sure which way I' supposed to import React in my React Native app.
If I need to use a hook like `useState` should I import React with: `import React, { useState } from 'react';`, `import { useState } from 'react';`, `import * as React from 'react';`, or `import * from 'react';`?
If I don't need any hooks should I use: `import React from 'react';`, `import 'react';`, `import * as React from 'react';`, or `import * from 'react';`?

Comment: 1 => import React, { useState } from 'react';  2 => import React from 'react';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of react version 17+, you don't need to `import React from 'react'` anymore. [Read more](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) about the JSX transformation.

Hooks are named exports, so you need to import hooks as:

```
import {useState, useEffect /* and others */} from 'react'
```

If you are using a react version below 17, you need to import `React`. Since `React` would be a default import these are all refer to the same thing:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as React from 'react'
```

So you should do `import React, {/* hooks you are using */} from 'react'`.

You can even do `import * as Whatever from 'react'`, since it is not a named export.